# What is the correct syntax declaring FQDN in host file for CentOS 7?

Tags: centos7, fqdn

First, I know how to declare FQDN but, I just want to know are they the same thing:

I have 2 VPSs running using Centos 7. When I look up at the */etc/hosts* file:

I found the entry of the host file for VPS 1 like this:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
```

But then the entry of host file for VPS 2 is like this:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain
```

I'm not sure why the 2 entries are different. My question is, what is the correct syntax for declaring this Fully Qualified Domain Name in your host file? Are those 2 lines can be used and has the same purpose?

Edit:

About the mark as duplicated answer, for explanation: The question asked there specifically about RHEL-based and Debian-based distros that have difference host setting but this question is about the same distro (CentOS 7) but has different host setting that might confuse some questioners to get the 'why' answer where the answer from the reference doesn't cover this.

Comment: `man hosts` answers your question.

Comment: unix/linux manuals are also easily [found online](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/hosts.5.html) nowadays.

Comment: So from the example given, It stated that, 127.0.0.1       localhost ->> is for IPv4

127.0.1.1       thishost.mydomain.org  thishost -->> is for FQDN

::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback -->> is for IPV6

Comment: But this still doesn't answer my question.

Comment: if I put thishost thishost.mydomain.org are they the same thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Even when your environment doesn't have man pages installed it doesn't mean you don't have access to them, either by installing them with `yum install man-pages man` or using online versions e.g. from [man.he.net](http://man.he.net/man5/hosts), [man7.org](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/hosts.5.html). or [linux.die.net](https://linux.die.net/man/5/hosts).*

The format is `IP_address canonical_hostname [aliases...]`. Therefore:

- `198.51.100.10 host.example.com host` is correct, as it has the FQDN (only without `.`) first
- `127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost` would be closest to that form
- `127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain` does the same, no any practical difference
- `127.0.0.1 localhost` would probably be just as sufficient.

Comment: Do you know what causes the entry to change in other VPS? They are the same distro (CentOS 7). Are those changes made by human or software?

Comment: Actually I like this answer because of the 2nd and third line and mostly the 3rd line said that it has no difference. That straight away answered my question. The manual didn't state about this form.. not sure if this is through testing.. and the person who marked this question. "already found answer" also need to re-read the content of the question not the title. TQ so much again even this is so old